# Numpy Truncation?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I am implementing a program that uses the Python Numpy package. I am trying to modify the elements of an array so that I simply take `elem[i][j]` and set it to `elem[i][j]/10`. However, I keep getting some sort of truncation where the elements are set to 0 after the operation. Here is my code:

```
for  word in allwords:
    for x in xrange(wordarrays[word].shape[0]):
        for y in xrange(wordarrays[word].shape[1]):
            wordarrays[word][x][y]=wordarrays[word][x][y]/10
```

In my code wordarrays is a dictionary from strings to arrays. When I simply print wordarrays[word][x][y]/10 truncation is not a problem and the float division proceeds as expected. I have checked and the arrays all have dtype=float64 so that shouldn't be the problem. I also tried modifying the array through the method presented here using [nditer](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html)

What is causing this truncation?
Thanks for the help!

---

To give some more detail regarding my unusual output. Before the division, the entries of wordarray['chen'] are as follows:

```
[[2. 3.]
 [4. 1.]]
```

After the division by 10 (or 10.0) I get this for the same array:

```
[[1.01000000e-04   1.20000000e-05]
[1.11001000e-01   1.00000000e-06]]
```

Which doesn't seem to make any sense. I recognize that the double for-loops aren't that pythonic but this was what I thought to try when iterating with np.nditer didn't work. To address some of the comments, I did try dividing by both 10 and 10.0. The outcome was the same.

Also, when I perform the same operation without replacing the entries of the array and just print the division, i.e.:

```
for  word in allwords:
  for x in xrange(wordarrays[word].shape[0]):
     for y in xrange(wordarrays[word].shape[1]):
            print wordarrays[word][x][y]/10
```

I get what is expected, namely:

```
[[0.2 0.3]
 [0.4 0.1]]
```

Comment: What do you mean, truncation? Can you illustrate your problem? Are you sure it's not a problem of display (ie, that the underlying data is actually not truncated)?

Comment: Side note: using loops isn't really numpythonic, you should probably be able to achieve the same result with `wordarrays[word]/=10` (provided the in-place division works OK with your `dtype`)

Comment: Are you sure `allwords` contain UNIQUE word elements?

Comment: Yes, it was instantiated as a set.

Answer (score 4):

You can significantly improve your performance doing this:

```
for word in allwords:
    wordarrays[word] /= 10.
```

Comment: Just an observation about the trick: everytime you put a decimal separator (`.`) after a literal number, this makes python interpreter to consider it a `float` instead of an integer, even if you don't put an implicit `0` after the decimal separator.

Answer (score 1):

I assume it's because you are dividing by an Integer and so Integer arithmetic is being performed. Try changing `10` to `10.0`.

e.g

```
for word in allwords:
    for x in xrange(wordarrays[word].shape[0]):
        for y in xrange(wordarrays[word].shape[1]):
            wordarrays[word][x][y]=wordarrays[word][x][y] / 10.0
```